# How to use special character (other language) for WTForms fields?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm using WTForms for my flask app. However the app is written in another language so it contains many special characters. So for my form i have:

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username     = TextField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email        = TextField('Email Address', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])
    accept_rules = BooleanField('I accept the site rules', [validators.Required()])
```

However I want to translate Username, Email Address etc... into my language so it should look like:

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username     = TextField('Tên', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email        = TextField('Địa Chỉ', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])
    accept_rules = BooleanField('Chấp Nhận', [validators.Required()])
```

Unfortunately i cannot compile it because python cannot read those special chars, which leads to the result that WTForms doesn't work correctly. Is it anyway that I can work around this problem? Or should I use a basic form post?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things you should try:

check if your file is UTF-8, and add 
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of your file

use unicode strings like u'thestring'

`class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username     = TextField(u'Tên', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email        = TextField(u'Địa Chỉ', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])
    accept_rules = BooleanField(u'Chấp Nhận', [validators.Required()])`

If you need to translate your app, you should take a look at Flask-babel: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/

Comment: thank you, that solves the problem! Another way doing that is i just print out {{ form.username }} in the html template, but that will limit the use of macro a bit.